# mgo.dial giving error "no reachable servers"

Tags: mongodb, go, error-handling, backend

while trying to create a session , i am getting "no reachable servers" error
below is the code

```
func getSession() *mgo.Session {
s, err := mgo.Dial("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return s
}
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WUaV.png)

Reason for error and solution

Comment: Assuming you're referring to https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo, you should be aware that it's abandoned. You'd be well advised to use the official driver instead: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver